# Fortify security issue "Unreleased resource stream"

Tags: java, security, inputstream

I am getting a fortify finding for "Unreleased resource stream" on the code below.

```java
Resource[] l_objResource = resourceLoader.getResources(configErrorCode);
Properties l_objProperty = null;
for (int i = 0; i < l_objResource.length; i++) {
    l_objProperty = new Properties();
    l_objProperty.load(l_objResource[i].getInputStream());
}
```

The function `loadErrorCode()` in `BaseErrorParser.java` sometimes fails to release a system resource allocated by `getInputStream();`

Can anyone explain the finding or help fix the issue?

---

From the comment below, but the context is not clear (JW):

```
ObjectInputStream l_objObjInputStream = null;
Map l_mapRet = null;
try {
    l_objObjInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(p_objFilename));
    Object l_objTemp = l_objObjInputStream.readObject();
    l_mapRet = (Map) l_objTemp;
} finally {
    if (l_objObjInputStream != null) {
        l_objObjInputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The function loadObjectFromFile() in BusinessObjectData.java sometimes fails to release a system resource allocated by FileInputStream()

Answer (score 5):

You are not closing the input stream which is opened by below line of code

```
l_objResource[i].getInputStream();
```

Usually fortify scanner reports Unreleased resource stream issue if there are any input or out streams which are opened but not closed after their usage. The ideal way to deal with these issues is to close all the opened streams in finally block so that even during exception scenarios they won't create any issues.

You can have a try - finally block around the code and close the stream as below.

```
Resource[] l_objResource = resourceLoader.getResources(configErrorCode);
Properties l_objProperty = null;
InputStream is = null;
for (int i = 0; i < l_objResource.length; i++) {
    l_objProperty = new Properties();
    try {
          is = l_objResource[i].getInputStream();
          l_objProperty.load(is);
    } finally {
          if(is!=null) {
              is.close();
          }
    }
}
```

Please check if it works in your case.

Comment: close method documentation: "Closes this input stream and releases any system resources associated with the stream.
**The close method of InputStream does nothing.**"
Fortify should skip this

Answer (score 2):

You can use Try with resource here. This will automatically close your stream.

```
Map l_mapRet = null;
try (ObjectInputStream l_objObjInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(p_objFilename))){
    Object l_objTemp = l_objObjInputStream.readObject();
    l_mapRet = (Map) l_objTemp;
} Catch(IOException E){
// Handle exception
}
```